# Tkinter, window not closing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a game which runs fine but when I close the window it gives this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed error
```

To fix it, I added this code, which I got from another question asked here, before the while loop.

```
x = True
def update_x():
    global x
    x = False

tk.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", update_x)
```

The while loop is:

```
while x == True:
    draw()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    tk.update()
```

The window doesn't close at all now. What am I doing wrong?
I don't really know how to use the mainloop method, is there any way to make it work using the while loop above?

Comment: If `tk` is the root window, you need to call `tk.destroy()` inside `update_x()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am pretty sure when you overwrite the 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' you should call `tk.destroy()` at the end of your function (update_x) or the window will not be destroyed. Second of all, if 'x' is always a boolean it is better to say: `while x: do_smth()` rather than `while x == True` and `while not x` instead of `while x == False`. If you still have problems after these changes there are two things you can do: Firstly, you can check if the window exists then update it like so: `if tk.winfo_exists(): tk.update()` or maybe at the end of your new protocol function (update_x), instead of `tk.destroy()` you can write `tk.quit()` to safely exit the program.

Comment: None of these are working. When I use `tk.quit()`, window doesn't close until the program breaks out of the while loop. If I do `tk.destroy()`, it gives the same error. Using 'if tk.winfo_exists(): tk.update()' gives this error `_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "winfo" command: application has been destroyed`

Comment: @gtr4 can you show us more of your code ?